# Magit status wired output (control sequences)

Tags: magit

When I use magit on a RHEL 7 box today, it gives me this output when checking magit-status:

[image: magit-status output]

Not sure what went wrong. Magit-version output is:

Magit 2.11.0, Git 2.14.1, Emacs 25.3.1, gnu/linux

The same Emacs setting works on Mac without any issue, haven't checked with a different Linux box yet.

Has anyone encountered the same problem before?

Thanks.

Edit:

Found the problem, thanks to icarus.
Sometime ago, I added

[color]
  ui = always

in my ~/.gitconfig. That's cause for all these control characters to show up. Removing it fixed it.

Comment: Identical ~/.gitconfig files on the two machines? Does removing ~/.gitconfig help?

Comment: Ah ha, yes, it's because the ```[color] ui = always``` setting in ~/.gitconfig

Thanks

Comment: @sudo Instead of appending the answer to the question itself please turn it into an actual, stand-alone answer. You can then accept your own answer and the question does not forever remain unanswered.

Comment: @tarsius Cool, got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two different machines had different `~/.gitconfig` files, in particular one had an option selecting color always rather than when the output was going to the terminal. The `^[[32m` and similar are ansi terminal color selecting sequences.